# How to manually remove php from init

Tags: ubuntu, php, upstart, init.d, update

I tried to remove php5-fpm from init (aka upstart) on my Lubuntu OS with the command:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f php5-fpm remove
```

but the symlink is still in `/etc/init.d/`; indeed php is started at boot.

What could have caused this issue, and how can I manually remove it from the boot in such a way that I can start/stop it using `sudo service php5-fpm start`/`stop`?

Comment: Why it was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses upstart for managing services. The service configuration is at */etc/init/php5-fpm.conf*. Don't delete this file, it will just be recreated when the package is updated. Instead, create the file */etc/init/php5-fpm.override* with the contents

> manual

Then you can start and stop it with `start php5-fpm` and `stop php5-fpm` but it won't be automatically started at boot. This is documented in the [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting).